# Problems with pytest's addoptions and dynamically parametrizing test fixtures

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am using pytest to do software testing lately but am coming across a problem when dynamically parameterizing test fixtures. When testing, I would like to be able to provide the option to:

A) Test a specific file by specifying its file name

B) Test all files in the installed root directory

Below is my current conftest.py. What I want it to do is if you choose option A (--file_name), create a parameterized test fixture using the file name specified. If you choose option B (--all_files), provide a list of all the files as a parameterized test fixture.

```
import os
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--file_name", action="store", default=[], help="Specify file-under-test")
    parser.addoption("--all_files", action="store_true", help="Option to test all files root directory")

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def file_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption('--file_name')

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'file_name' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if metafunc.config.option.all_files:
            all_files = list_all_files()
        else:
            all_files = "?"
        metafunc.parametrize("file_name", all_files)


def list_all_files():
    root_directory = '/opt/'
    if os.listdir(root_directory):
        # files have .cool extension that need to be split out
        return [name.split(".cool")[0] for name in os.listdir(root_directory)
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_directory, name))]
    else:
        print "No .cool files found in {}".format(root_directory)
```

The more I fiddle with this, I only can get one of the options working but not the other...what do I need to do to get both options (and possibly more) dynamically create parametrized test fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'file_name' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        files = []
        if metafunc.config.option.all_files:
            files = list_all_files()
        fn = metafunc.config.option.file_name
        if fn:
            files.append(fn)
        metafunc.parametrize('file_name', all_files, scope='module')
```

No need to define `file_name` function.

Comment: This is partially working...it's really bizarre, but it looks like some of my tests pass and some don't. For the failures, I end up with an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'. It seems like sometimes I get an unparametrized fixture because I can see in the test log output the entire list of files  instead of just 1 entry.

Comment: @t88 That's probably because `default=[]` in `parser.addoption("--file_name", ...)` is wrong. For consistency you should do `default=''`. If it doesn't help then show us the test. Did you remove the `file_name` function?

Comment: You're right! Also it turns out that files.append(fn) was returning a list and if I specified a file_name, it would return a list and not use the specified string as a parametrized test fixture. Thanks!

Comment: and yes, removed file_name function